# Quels adverbes s'utilisent après les participes passés ?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes, syntaxe

Selon un livre de grammaire, les adverbes sont généralement trouvés après les verbes conjugués :

> Tu as vite oublié.
>
> Tu as complètement oublié.

Mais il y a des exceptions. En faisant une recherche sur le corpus linguee.fr, on trouve beaucoup d'exemples de

> ... a vite oublié ...

mais pas d'exemple* de

> ... a oublié vite...

Par contre, les deux formes suivantes

> ... a complètement oublié ...
>
> ... a oublié complètement ...

sont également attestées. On en déduit que l'adverbe vite ne se comporte pas comme l'adverbe complètement, mais pourquoi ? Comment savoir si un adverbe peut être placé après le participe ou pas ?

*En fait on en trouve un, mais celui-ci à l'air d'un texte anglais passé sur Google Translate.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ oups, je l'ai changé

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de règle malheureusement... Mais s'il en existe une, j'aimerais la connaitre.

Comment: *Quels adverbes s'utilisent-ils* me semble incorrect, j'aurais écrit *quels adverbes s'utilisent*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps merci, c'est changé

Comment: Ce genre de question m'embête. Il faudrait écrire tout un article. En plus, posée par un francophone....what's the point.

Comment: @Lambie je ne suis pas du tout un francophone, et je veux savoir comment utiliser les adverbes, c'est ça, the point !

Comment: I just think that to ask such a broad question here is not what this site is about. What if I said: How do you conjugate verbs in French? That is so broad....any of these broad questions are answered in a myriad of places on the internet in a very structured way. a oublé is not a participe passé. It's the past tense.  A participe passé is: la petite fille oublié dans la rue par sa mère.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve parfois dans les livres et blogs de grammaire que l'adverbe se place après le verbe aux temps simples et après le participe passé aux temps composés. Si effectivement c'est quasiment toujours vrai pour les temps simples, c'est plus compliqué que ça pour les temps composés. La distinction adverbes courts et adverbes longs que font certains n'est pas non plus une règle infaillible. Je préfère suivre *la grammaire Larousse du français contemporain* que j'adapte à ma sauce.

**Les adverbes de lieu** se placent après le participe passé :

> Je n'ai pas vu le trou dans la nuit et **je suis tombé dedans**.
>   Je l'ai **posé ici**/plus bas, etc.

**Les adverbes de temps** se placent en général après le participe passé,

> Je me suis **couché tard** et je me suis **levé tôt**.
>   Il est **reparti avant-hier**.

Cependant *souvent, toujours, autrefois, maintenant, (tout) juste* se placent avant le participe passé :

> Je suis **souvent allé** en Italie.
>   Ils sont **tout juste arrivés**.

*Longtemps* peut se placer avant ou après :

> J'ai marché longtemps avant d'arriver.
>   J'ai longtemps marché avant d'arriver. (plus littéraire)

Les **adverbes de manière** courts se placent avant le participe passé :

> J'ai **bien mangé**.
>   J'ai **mal dormi**.
>   Il a **parlé** (tout) **bas**.

Les adverbes de manière longs se placent de préférence après le participe passé :

> Je lui **ai parlé gentiment**.
>   Il m'**a regardé longuement**.

Cependant on peut les placer avant le participe passé, ce qui crée un effet de style en donnant plus de valeur à l'adverbe.

> Je lui ai **gentiment parlé**.
>   Il m'a **longuement regardé**.

La place de l'adverbe par rapport au participe passé donne parfois un sens différent à l'adverbe :

> J'ai vu juste. (→ Je ne me suis pas trompé)

à différencier de :

> J'ai juste vu ce qui se passait avant de partir. (→ J'ai seulement vu...)

Les adverbes de quantité se placent en général avant le participe passé :

> J'ai **peu mangé** et **trop bu**.

Je ne pense pas avoir été exhaustif. À compléter donc.

Comment: Le fait qu'il y ait tant de nuances avec l'adverbe, qu'est-ce que ça veut dire à son sujet, ou à celui de son rôle dans la langue, selon vous ? Ou ce sont simplement tous des usages spécifiques sédimentés sous l'influence de l'euphonie ?

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃  Avertissement : je ne suis pas linguiste (au sens moderne du terme), ce que je vais dire n'a pas de valeur scientifique et reflète une analyse personnelle. Hétérogénéité dans la morphologie,  origine (latin, création par composition ou dérivation),  fonction qui peut les lier à différentes parties du discours et les rapprocher tantôt de l'adjectif, tantôt de la préposition, voire des conjonctions ; sachant que selon leur place ils peuvent soit prendre un sens différent ou donner un sens différent à la phrase, ça tient pour moi de "son rôle dans la langue".

Answer (score 2):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une règle fixe. Je pense que c'est une question de *feeling*.

Dans ton exemple avec *vite*, c'est vrai que *a vite oublié* sonne mieux que *a oublié vite*.

Mais dans cet exemple :

> Ils ont travaillé vite.
>
> Ils ont vite travaillé.

Les deux phrases sont parfaitement correctes. Mais elles ne sont pas interchangeables. Si quelqu'un dit *Ils ont à peine commencé à travailler, et ils ont déjà presque fini !*, tu ne peux que répondre *C'est parce qu'ils ont travaillé vite*. Tu décris la manière dont ils ont travaillé.

*Ils ont vite travaillé* comporte plutôt le sens de *Ils ont vite commencé à travailler*. Tu évoques le temps qui s'est écoulé entre *avant qu'ils ne travaillent* et *quand ils ont commencé à travailler*.

J'ai l'impression que lorsque *vite* est placé entre l'auxiliaire et le participe passé, on parle du temps qu'il a fallu pour commencer l'action, alors que quand il est placé après, on parle du temps qu'il a fallut pour exécuter l'action.

> Je suis entré dans une maison, mais elle était sombre et inquiétante, alors je suis vite parti.

... signifierait que je n'y suis pas resté longtemps.

> Je suis entré dans une maison, mais elle était sombre et inquiétante, alors je suis parti vite.

... signifierait que je suis parti en courant.

Je ne serais pas choqué par cette phrase :

> Je suis vite parti vite.

... soit *je suis parti immédiatement, et à toute vitesse*.

---

C'était l'emploi de *vite* avec un temps composé, mais qu'en est-il au présent ? *Je pars vite* peut vouloir dire les deux :

> Je pars immédiatement.
>
> Je pars en courant.

N'est-ce pas la même chose en anglais ? *Go fast!* ne peut-il pas signifier à la fois *Go now!* (even if you only walk, go now) et *Run!* ?

---

Un autre exemple à l'impératif :

> Vite, fais tes devoirs !

... voudrait plutôt dire *fais tes devoirs tout de suite*, même si ça te prend trois heures.

> Fais vite tes devoirs !

... voudrait plutôt dire *fais tes devoirs rapidement parce qu'après tu dois aller te coucher*.

C'est mon ressenti, je ne sais pas si une règle peut confirmer ou infirmer ce que j'ai écrit.