# Position of the adverb when modifying an infinitive

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, syntaxe

I'm trying to understand where the adverb goes when it modifies an infinitive in a phrase with complements and prepositions.

In a sentence such as *il ne suffit pas de le faire* where I want to modify *le faire* with an adverb such as *tout simplement* to even just *simplement*, I would be inclined to put the adverb after the infinitive. However, my understanding of rules governing adverb use has always been somewhat rudimentary and I'd like to get a better grasp on why adverbs go where they do, especially when they are modifying unconjugated verbs.

If anyone can help me to understand these rules I'd really appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: The fact that the verb is in the infinitive or another form does not influence the place of the adverb.  The place of the adverb is a somewhat fuzzy thing because it can vary a lot depending onwhat you want to say. There's [an answer here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/21798/358) about the place of adverbs, if it doesn't answer your question can you give more context/specify what  meaning you  want to achieve with *simplement*  that could be placed in three different places in your sentence as it stands.

Comment: @Laure I checked out that link but I'm not sure it answers my question, especially if it's the case that the adverb can go both before and after the verb to convey different meanings. I'm trying to express "it's not enough just to do it" (as in, there are other things we also need to do; these other requirements are included in the rest of my text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place of the adverb is a somewhat fuzzy thing because it can vary a lot depending on what you want to say. It seems that you do not want to modify the infinitive *faire* but *il suffit que*.

I would say the most usual way to say it would be:

> Il ne suffit (tout) simplement pas de le faire.

If you wrote:

> Il ne suffit pas de le faire (tout) simplement.

could be ambiguous since, according to the more general context in which you use the sentence, it might  be understood as modifying *le faire*, thus meaning "it's not enough to do it in a simple manner".

Note that you could have *(de) le faire* at the beginning of the sentence. It would give more importance to the words but would not change the meaning:

> Le faire ne suffit (tout) simplement pas.*

Instead of *simplement* you could also use the adverb *uniquement* or the adverbial phrase *rien ... que*.

> Il ne suffit pas rien que de le faire.
>   Il ne suffit pas uniquement de le faire.
>   Uniquement le faire ne suffit pas.
>   Le faire uniquement ne suffit pas.

Some people would even use the adverb *juste*:

> Il ne suffit pas juste de le faire.
>   Juste le faire  ne suffit pas.

but a lot of (other) people consider that this use of *juste* is an anglicism.

---

*<sub>You don't need the *de* in that case.</sub>